# How can I non-destructively query the status of a SPWorkItem?

Tags: timer-jobs

Suppose I have a custom timer job that processes work items. How can I check whether the timer job has processed a specific `SPWorkItem` without interfering with the actual processing?

If I try to initialize an `SPWorkItemCollection` using `SPSite` and the work item type's ID, I can get a reference to the work item. But initializing that collection also seems to remove the work item from the queue!

I tried calling `SPWorkItemCollection.RevertInProgressWorkItem`, but that doesn't seem to do anything. If I reinitialize the `SPWorkItemCollection`, it doesn't contain my work item anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a subcollection and work on that. Apparently you need to do this to set the parent web. Assuming workItems is your SPWorkItemCollection:

```
var subWorkItems = workItems.SubCollection(site, web, 0, (uint)workItems.Count);
```

Now call methods such as RevertInProgressWorkItem on subWorkItems.

I also found that this puts the item back on the queue but with a delivery time 10 minutes in the future. You change this by setting the delivery time explicitly.

Waldek has a [good blog post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/processing-items-work-item-timer-jobs-sharepoint-2010/) on work item timer jobs.